# Select record from database, with date "As-On", passed date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, date-range

I have a table in database with start_date, end_date and I want to fetch record from database, with date filter, as fetch those records **"As on given date"**.
Eg:

```
Id   start_date    end_date
1    1980-01-01    1984-12-31
2    1985-01-01    2009-12-31
3    2010-01-01    2018-12-31
4    2019-01-01    null
5    1940-01-01    null
```

So now If I pass on date (**Desired Output**)

```
**1940-01-01**, it should return #Id=5 (number of records == 1)
**1980-01-02**, it should return #Id=1,5 (number of records == 2)
**1985-01-01**, it should return #Id=1,2,5 (number of records == 3)
**2010-01-01**, it should return #Id=1,2,3,5 (number of records == 4)
**2019-01-01**, it should return #Id=1,2,3,4,5 (number of records == 5)
**2021-01-01**, it should return #Id=1,2,3,4,5 (number of records == 5)
```

I tried a number of queries, but none seemed to work like

```
select * from table where (end_date <= '1980-01-02' or end_date is null)

select * from table where '1980-01-01 00:00:00' between start_date and coalesce(end_date, '2999-12-31')

select * from table where (end_date <= '1980-01-01 00:00:00' or end_date is null) and start_date <= '1980-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Why would you return `id = 1` after 1984-12-31?  Your desired results don't make sense.  Why would 2021-01-01 return no records?

Comment: Because that is history and I want that records to be displayed as historical (Has happened before or equal to this date)

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Answer (score 0):

Use the `infinity` `timestamp` literals and `between` for this:

```
select * 
  from "table"
 where '1940-01-01' between coalesce(start_date, timestamp '-infinity')
                        and coalesce(end_date, timestamp 'infinity')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic that makes sense to me is:

```
select t.*
from t
where :date >= start_date and
      (:date <= end_date or end_date is null);
```

However, this is not consistent with your stated results.  It conforms to my reading of what you want.